# Does Java's LinkedHashMap maintain the order of keys?

Tags: java, dictionary, set, linkedhashmap

When LinkedHashMap.keySet() is called, will the order of the Set returned be the same as the order the keys were added in?

Comment: For those coming from PHP, let me help them by pointing out that a LinkedHashMap behaves very much like a PHP array.

Answer (score 51):

Yes.

See: [LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html):

> This linked list defines the iteration
>   ordering, which is normally the order
>   in which keys were inserted into the
>   map (insertion-order).

and from the [HashMap#keySet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#keySet%28%29) documentation:

> The set [returned] is backed by the map, so
>   changes to the map are reflected in
>   the set, and vice-versa.

Comment: @Tom thanks, I'm still not convinced that this is explicit.  Why wouldn't LinkedHashMap.keySet() return a subclass of Set with fixed ordering?

Comment: Because if it returned a SortedSet, then LinkedHashMap would be adding the requirement that its keys are of a type which implements Comparable, or that a comparator function be supplied.  This is NOT required by Map.  Check out the SortedSet documentation: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html.  Not having this requirement allows even keys which do not implement Comparable to be used in a LinkedHashMap, which is the more general case.  LinkedHashMap's implementation might even return a SortedSet if its keys ARE Comparable, but it simply isn't REQUIRED to.

Comment: Of course, the contract of LinkedHashMap says that it maintains INSERTION ordering, which may not be the NATURAL ordering.  So in that case, a SortedSet wouldn't work at all---the keys simply wouldn't be sorted in that manner.

Comment: @Tom I didn't mention `SortedSet` and there could be an implementation of Set which implied order other than natural order.

Comment: @Alison: I mentioned `SortedSet` because what is a subclass of `Set` with a fixed ordering other than a `SortedSet`?

Comment: @Tom `LinkedHashSet`?  This might seem a more logical assumption in this case.

Comment: But `LinkedHashSet` does not implement `SortedSet'.

Comment: @Tom exactly - you asked for an ordered `Set` which does not implement `SortedSet`, and I provided an example.

Comment: @Alison It does return a subclass of Set with fixed ordering, if you look at the source code. The HashSet's keySet() method uses a custom Set class which reads off of an iterator. The LinkedHashMap overrides that iterator to read from it's own linked list of map entries. 
http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/HashMap.java.html
http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.java.html

Comment: @Roman thanks, nice info.  I wonder if this could change in future, and if it could be dependant on the Java implementation (i.e. Oracle vs others)

Comment: Is keySet order debatable? http://stackoverflow.com/a/10387318/231382

Comment: "...which is _normally_ the order..." isn't terribly precise (it could have meant sometimes it's random!). The important line from the LinkedHashMap javadoc is in the opening sentence: "with _predictable iteration order_".

Comment: I agree @bacar, I don't know why they say _normally_.  I'm very curious why they put it that way...

Answer (score 41):

[Yes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html). The exception is that when a key is reinserted, it appears in the order in which it was first inserted to the list.

Comment: +1 Good catch on that corner case.

Comment: Actually, the exception is for when the key is **reinserted**, not deleted and reused.  The case is when you call `put(key, value)` for a key that was already in the map.  (The javadoc explains this clearly.)