# Map to Charsequence[] but not in order

Tags: java, android

I am having a Map and converting to charsequence[] by using the

```
final CharSequence[] treatmentNameList = treatmentListMap.keySet().toArray(new CharSequence[treatmentListMap.size()]);
```

but the value at position of charsequence[0] and map 0 is not is getting varied. how to get same values in both charsequence and map.
 i tried this also

```
final CharSequence[] treatmentNameList = treatmentListMap.keySet().toArray(new CharSequence[0]);
```

Comment: Can you please provide an example of the input you have and the expected output?

Comment: 0-treatmentListMap<Iron,32> 1-treatmentListMap<calcium,89>.......in charsequence[0]=vitamins   im expecting for Iron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting a key `Set`.  A set does not in general guarantee any order, hence the order being different for different calls.  You may have more luck with a `LinkedHashMap`, if you are able to control the implementation of the map you're using.  See the Javadocs for more information about them.

This post:

[Does Java's LinkedHashMap maintain the order of keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3478061/does-javas-linkedhashmap-maintain-the-order-of-keys)

has more information for you.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by user1111284, it perfectly works. Please look into the below code

```
public class MapToCharSequenceTest {

public static void main(String[] args){
    LinkedHashMap<String,String> contents = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();

    contents.put("brass","rod");
    contents.put("Silver","spoon");
    contents.put("gold","ring");
    contents.put("iron","plate");
    Set<String> set = contents.keySet();
    final CharSequence[] charsequence  = set.toArray( new CharSequence[contents.size()]);
    for(CharSequence c : charsequence){
        System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Please read the javadoc for CharSequence. Have you seen http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html?