# fetching from LinkedHashMap HashMap based on index

Tags: java

I have a `LinkedHashMap<String, String>`, which contains some pre-populated data. Now I have a `String` value, which will match to a key in the above `LinkedHashMap`. What can I do to retrieve the very next key of the above match?

Example:

```java
LinkedHashMap hm = new LinkedHashMap();
hm.put("a",1);
hm.put("b",2);
hm.put("c",3);
hm.put("d",4);
hm.put("e",5);
```

Now I have a `String`, say "d" . What is the optimal way if I have to retrieve the value of "e" from the above `Map`?

One way I have found is to convert the map key into `LinkedHashSet`. Now iterate the `Set`. Compare the value and get the next value. But isn't there any API available, which can get me all this?

Comment: Please see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13581997/how-get-value-from-linkedhashmap-based-on-index-not-on-key

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3478061/does-javas-linkedhashmap-maintain-the-order-of-keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there is no straightforward way to do it but you can implement an utility method that would fulfil your need:

```java
public class IndexedMap
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    LinkedHashMap hm = new LinkedHashMap();
    hm.put("a",1);
    hm.put("b",2);
    hm.put("c",3);
    hm.put("d",4);
    hm.put("e",5);
    System.out.println(getNextItem(hm, "d"));
  }

  public static Object getNextItem(LinkedHashMap<String, String> hMap, String item){

    int index = 0;
    List<String> keys = new ArrayList<String>(hMap.keySet());
    for (String key : keys)
    {
      if (item.equals(key))
        break;

      index++;
    }
    return (index < keys.size() - 1) ? hMap.values().toArray()[++index] : 0;
  }

}
```

Comment: I think, OP didn't mean `O(n)` version.

Comment: Absolutely it didn't mean it, but it wasn't restrictive neither.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, there is no way the get "the next entry after a given key" from a `LinkedHashMap` that is better than `O(N)`.

Now, if you were willing to create your own version of the class (e.g. by copying the code and modifying it), then you could implement this as an `O(1)` operation.  You might even be able to implement this as a subclass of `LinkedHashMap` ... but I suspect you will be stymied by the fact that some of the relevant methods and fields are not accessible from a subclass (in a different package).